# How to remove the default app navigation header on a android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I seen some questions pertaining to this, however there solutions where to do it in the code. I would like to get rid of the navigation header that comes default on the android app when selecting a template.

Now, I do not want to do this with java code. How can I remove the panel from my activity_main.xml?

This is the header I am taking about:
[image]

I would like to remove it completely, not temporarily, to have more space to place elements in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as a no title bar theme in the activity's xml in the AndroidManifest

```
  <activity 
    android:name=".yourActivityName"
    android:label="@string/a_string"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

To add Theme.NoTitleBar in application is remove all the page theme effects. If you want to remove the action on First screen add the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar". Save the theme for remaining pages.

Also you can create your own theme,

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

and do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to your activity/app theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity apply the theme in manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is define a new style within `values/styles.xml` so it looks like this :

```
<style name = "AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

be noticed that you should change the `AndroidManifest.xml` too like this :

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your onCreate in Main Activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Comment: The OP didn't want to do this in code: `"Now, I do not want to do this with java code."`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove for preview , click on `Apptheme`  beside api 25 and select any theme which says `.NoActionBar` . If you want to remove inside app then follow any above method

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it:

1. via java code

   ```
   public class ActivityName extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
   ```

   }
2. via xml in activity tag, add:

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"